# java check user digital signature verified by javascript

Tags: javascript, signed

How can I check if user click yes (trust my application) for my signed Application from javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var check = confirm("Do you trust this app?");
if (check) { //user clicked ok
    //do whatever
}
```

If your application is on a website, you could place the `<applet>` tag within a `<div id="app" style="none">`. Then you could replace `//do whatever` with this:

```
document.body.getElementById("app").style = 'block';
```

Comment: Yes my applicatin on a web site. Bu i wanna programmatic check, I wantto to learn which button pressed by user. If user press run or cancel ?